# How integrate samsung IAP in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, flutter-in-app-purchase

I'm about to release a flutter application on the samsung store, galaxy store.

I haven't found any compatible package or guide online that allows me to **integrate in flutter**, the **Samsung IAP** feature.

Has anyone done this before or know anything about it?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't think there is currently any flutter package aimed at Samsung IAP. Nor have Samsung created anything to support Flutter specifically - their example apps are Java and Kotlin, which means you will have to use their API and HTTP calls, I guess. This seems to be the relevant documentation: https://developer.samsung.com/iap/programming-guide/integrate-iap-helper-into-your-app.html

Sorry it's not better news :-(